# Is This Relational Database Sound or Can it be Improved?

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database

I am trying to create a database for an online instrumental shop. I designed this database and added a cart table but I don't know if this is a good implementation for a online shop with cart.

[image: Database Design]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database sounds ohk and can be improved in many ways to make it even perfect one.
The following links gives u more detail in depth
https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/Relational_Database_Design.html